# Question on thinking about an electric charge as multiple electric charges in special relativity

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, forces

I understand that thinking about permanent magnets as a rotating loop of charged particles can be used to derive things like how an electric charge will be effected by the magnetic field, and to derive how the magnets would interact with each other.  So while a permanent magnet may not actually be a rotating loop of charged particles it can still be a useful fiction to pretend that it is similar to how electric field lines are a useful fiction for understanding electric forces.  Thinking about one electric charge as multiple electric charges can also be useful for deriving and understanding $E{\propto}Q$ and $F_E{\propto}Q_1Q_2$.

Let's say that there are two electric charges A and B, and we want to know the electromagnetic four force acting on A at spacetime point C, from B at spacetime point D as D and C have lightlike separation and D happened first.  Let's say that we know the velocity B had at point D relative to A at point C, and at point D B was moving close to the speed of light relative to A at point C.

My question is if I treat A as being multiple electric charges moving at nearly the speed of light relative to each other, but being at the same spacetime coordinates, would I get the same answer as I would if I treated A as being one object?  Assume that I treat objects occupying the same spacetime coordinates as not interacting with each other.

The reason I ask this question is that I think that while electric charges having the exact same spacetime coordinates may not be realistic I think that it could be a potentially useful fiction to help with understanding and deriving the real world electromagnetic four force equation in special relativity.

Comment: If B and D are different locations, why do you think that treating the charges as being on the same location could be useful? It is a good approximation if you are observing from far away though.